# Converting "child of" animation to regular location one

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature, export

I have an animation involving two nodes: there is a character, who takes an object to his hand. Both character and the object have an armature, and there is a "child of" modifier between the bones. I animate the influence parameter of the parameter putting a keyframe of 0 when the hand is far from the object and 1 when it gets close to it. The animation works fine in Blender.

Now, I would like to export the animation to a game engine (Godot). The game engine doesn't understand the child of modifier between the bones, so by default only the character's hand, but not the object, gets animated after importing to the game engine.

Is there a way to transform the animation in Blender to replace the "child of" relationship of the object with a sequence of keyframes copied from the character's bone, such that I can export the animations to the game engine as two independent ones?

I know I can make the animations separately from the start, but it's more tedious than using the child of modifier.

Comment: What about Pose > Animation > Bake Action, then in the pop-up panel enable Visual Keying?

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Feel free to promote to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your bone and in *Pose* mode go into the header menu > *Pose > Animation > Bake Action*, then in the pop-up panel enable *Visual Keying*, it will give you a series of keyframes.